# Вопрос состоит в том как правильно организовать фильтр на стороне клиента

Tags: jquery, фильтр

Как правильно организовать фильтр для выбора бренда и цены?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>Фильтр</h3>
</div>

<hr>

<h3>Каталог</h3>
<div class="catalog">
  <div>Lenovo цена 8000</div>
  <div>Asus цена 8000</div>
  <div>MSI цена 20000</div>
  <div>Asus цена 15000</div>
  <div>Asus цена 9000</div>
  <div>HP цена 17000</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можете попробовать сами сделать по [этому примеру.](https://jsfiddle.net/d1eLfjkh/)

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно организовать фильтр для выбора бренда и цены?

Не самый оптимальный вариант, но все же.

```js
var products = [{
    name: "HP",
    price: 8000
  },
  {
    name: "Asus",
    price: 8000
  },
  {
    name: "MSI",
    price: 20000
  },
  {
    name: "Asus",
    price: 15000
  },
  {
    name: "Asus",
    price: 9000
  },
  {
    name: "HP",
    price: 17000
  },
]
//----------------------------------------------------------------
var unq = [] // Только наименование
// Оставляет массив продуктов
unq = products.map(item => item.name)
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)

var sel = $('select')
var cat = $('.catalog')
// Селект из уникальных продуктов
$.each(unq, function(i, p) {
  sel.append('<option value="' + p + '">' + p + '</option>')
})
// Построение каталога из всех продуктов
$.each(products, function(i, p) {
  // Создание нового элемента для продукта
  let div = $('<div/>')
    .attr({
      class: 'item',
      "data-prod-name": p.name,
      "data-price": p.price
    })
    .text(p.name + ' цена ' + p.price);
  cat.append(div);
})

// Если есть изменения в селекте
sel.on('change', function(e) {
  var filter = $(this).val()
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  cat.children().each(function(i) {
    if (filter !== "All" && filter !== $(this).attr('data-prod-name')) {
      $(this).hide()
    } else {
      $(this).show()
    }

  })
})

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Филтр по цене
$('.price').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var val = $(this).val()
    cat.children().each(function(i) {
      //--------------------------------------------
      // Mathjs вроде они лучше, чем обычный eval..
      //--------------------------------------------
      if (!math.eval($(this).attr('data-price') + val)) {
        $(this).hide()
      } else if (val.length === 0) {
        // Фильтрует только в случае Only if nothing was filtered
        // когда была предыдущая фильтрация
        // Выбор из селекта
        sel.trigger('change')
      } else {
        $(this).show()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.0.1/math.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="" id="">
  <option value="All">All</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="price" name="byprice" placeholder="filter by price" title="Filter by: &gt; | &gt;&equals; | &lt; | &lt;&equals; | &equals;&equals; | &equals;&equals;8000 [Enter]">
<span>Filter by: &gt; | &gt;&equals; | &lt; | &lt;&equals; | &equals;&equals; | &equals;&equals;8000 [Enter]</span>
<hr>
<h1>Каталог</h1>
<div class="catalog">

</div>
<hr>
```

P.S.: На весь экран.